# Rails: How to setup a form with multiple select tags with a HABTM relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have `bands`, `genres` and `bands_genres` database tables with a HABTM relationship

I have a form for creating new bands and I want users to be able to select 3 genres from 3 different dropdown select menus.

How would I set up my form (and my `create` method) so that when the user selects those 3 genres, it correctly adds the relationship to my `bands_genres` table?

I'm running Rails 3.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi the form must be similar to the HABTM through checkboxes Something like

```
<%form_for @band do |f|%>
  ...
  <%= select_tag "band[genree_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(@first_genrees, "name", "id")%>
  <%= select_tag "band[genree_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(@second_genrees, "name", "id")%>
  <%= select_tag "band[genree_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(@third_genrees, "name", "id")%>
<%end%>
```

after form submit relationships should be changed

Comment: Is there another way to write this "band[genree_ids][]" param? How does this work?

Comment: Is there a way to use f.select instead of select_tag? I tried but it is not working.

Answer (score 8):

You can simplify your code by doing it via 1 select which allows you to select multiple choices,

```
<%= collection_select(:band, :genre_ids, Genre.all, :id, :name,{:include_blank => 'None'},
{:multiple => true, :name=>'band[genre_ids][]',:selected => 0}) %>
```

The :selected => 0 , sets the default selection to None

gl